# Cloning SAS RAID1 array with OS partition to a new SATA array?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hardware-raid, raid1, ibm-xseries, cloning

I have two RAID1 arrays, first one is made of SAS disks and that's where the OS (Win Server 2k8 r2) is, the second RAID1 array contains SATA SSDs (and hold the database).

Server is IBM's System x3650 M3 with ServeRAID M5014 SAS/SATA RAID Controller.

What I want to is to move the first array from SAS disks to a couple of new SSDs. I don't have a means to clone the SAS disk to a new SSD from another machine, but have to use this same computer.

What would be the best way to do it?

I already made a Windows Server Backup on another disk but that's not a clone and I should be able to restore it with Windows installation disk.

Or should I just make a clone of the OS partition using another array where I temporarily place Linux (it would be easier for me to use Linux tools for cloning)?

Keep in mind I have to use this computer to do it. Will any of the above affect the RAID configuration? For example, I make a clone of the SAS disk using the third array from which I booted in Linux and then remove both SAS disks replacing them with a cloned SATA SSD and an empty one - should everything "just work" or will I have to do something with RAID configuration first? If I mess with the configuration, I suppose I won't just be able to go back if I want to (put the original SAS disks back and have everything run as it used to do)?

Comment: If supported by your RAID controller and your SSD's are not sized differently: Remove 1 disk from the mirror, replace it with your ssd,  let the RAID controller sync the disks and once the mirror is healthy repeat and remove spinning disk number 2 and replace with the second SSD.

Comment: That's the thing, it seems it's not supported. Even though the controller supports both SAS and SATA disks, I can't mix SAS and SATA disks in one array. :/